# How to get radar images to a .NET program

Tags: .net, xml, image, soap

How do I get radar images to a .Net program using this service: http://www.nws.noaa.gov/forecasts/xml/

I literally have no clue where to start. If someone could provide some sample code or maybe direct me to a tutorial of some kind that would be awesome.

Thanks Alot

Comment: Please tell me you don't work for the Federal Aviation Administration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click your project, Add Service Reference...  Then under Address put in http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl and click Go.  Choose a Namespace in the bottom.  Then I think you can use it something like:

```
using AppClass.ServiceReference1;
...
ndfdXMLPortTypeClient service = new ndfdXMLPortTypeClient();
string data = service.NDFDgen(39, -77, productType.timeseries, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, new weatherParametersType() { maxt = true });
```

`data` is "DWML encoded NDFD data for a point", whatever that means (though I would guess D* Weather Markup Language).  I don't know how to decode DWML, or what that data contains.  You may need another method to get radar images.

Comment: That is a great start, thank you very much. Would it be possible for you to elaborate a little bit more on your last line of code though?

Comment: @JCwhisman - That depends on how they implemented it.  It looked like NDFDgen might "generate" something, so I picked that.  You may have to pick another method.  Which method to use and what the result type would be documented.  I updated my answer a bit.